# What mission order should I use in order to get an orbital command by "The Dig"?

Tags: starcraft-2

I would like to have 'scan' for 'The Dig' mission.

Which other mission should I pass to get it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[According to Liquipedia](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Campaign/Armory#Terran_Building), you must complete 12 missions to unlock the Orbital Command upgrade in the Armory. Going by the prerequisite structure [here](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Campaign#Missions), one possible mission order may be:

1. Liberation Day
2. The Outlaws
3. Zero Hour
4. The Evacuation
5. Outbreak
6. Smash and Grab
7. The Devil's Playground
8. Welcome to the Jungle
9. Safe Haven (or Haven's Fall)
10. The Great Train Robbery
11. Cutthroat
12. Engine of Destruction

Comment: +1: It's worth noting though, that the achievements on *The Great Train Robbery* and *Welcome to the Jungle* are possibly the hardest achievements to get, so anything that puts those missions earlier than they have to be is to be avoided. Scanning isn't *that* big a deal on this map, as long as you use the cannon intelligently.